# android canvas click

Tags: android, canvas, click, coordinates

there is class, that draws on canvas some field

```
  package com.cerbertek;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class PlayGameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private CanvasThread canvasthread;
    private Context mContext;
    private Region firstRec;

    private class CanvasThread extends Thread  {
        private SurfaceHolder _holder;
        private boolean _run = false;

        public CanvasThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            _holder = surfaceHolder;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            _run = run;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas  c;
            while (_run) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    c = _holder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (_holder) {
                        onDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        _holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public PlayGameView (Context  context, AttributeSet  attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        canvasthread = new CanvasThread(getHolder());
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas  canvas) {     
            Paint  paint = new Paint (); 
            Bitmap wrench = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wrench);
            canvas.drawColor(Color .BLACK);
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    int left = canvas.getWidth()/2 - wrench.getWidth()*2 + j*wrench.getWidth();
                    int top = 0  + i*wrench.getHeight();
                    canvas.drawBitmap(wrench, left, top, null);

                    Log.d(i + " " + j, left+ " " + top);
                }
            }

    }



    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {


    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        canvasthread.setRunning(true);
        canvasthread.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        boolean retry = true;
        canvasthread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
                try {
                        canvasthread.join();
                        retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException  e) {
                        // we will try it again and again...
                }
        }
    }
}
```

so i want to detect where i click on(for exemple there is 2 rects and i want to detect what rect i click on). i can set *setOnClickListener* to my view, but how to get position of click?
then i want to set the regions while drawing( it is right, yeah? or not?) and in activity i'll check is click coordinates contains regions

so
1) how can i get coord of click
2) what is the pretty good way to do do all that stuff, because my ideas are poor often

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the `setOnTouchListener`.

The `OnTouchListener` implements a method with the following signature:

> public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)

The MotionEvent has information about where the touch actually happened. (`event.getX()` and `event.getY()`)